# Any success using Vagrant + Samba for Drupal Projects?

Tags: virtual-machine

I was desperately hoping that I'd be able to mitigate the ridiculously awful performance of Drupal in our Windows + Vagrant dev environments by using Samba rather than Virtualbox shared folders, but so far I've had exactly zero success. Has anyone else succeeded? If so, anything you can share to help?

I haven't been able to get past this error when attempting to mount the network share:

> Failed to mount folders in Linux guest. This is usually because
>   the "vboxsf" file system is not available. Please verify that
>   the guest additions are properly installed in the guest and
>   can work properly.

We're running:

- Win7/Win8 host
- Ubuntu 12.04 guest
- Vagrant 1.6.3 + vb-guest plugin
- Virtualbox 4.3.12

I've seen indications around the Google-sphere that I can SSH into the guest and do some magical symlinking, but my vagrant box is powered off when the mount fails. I can't access the box.

Help?

Comment: I'm not sure you'll find a huge amount (or at least enough) of Vagrant know-how here, especially as the problem you're having doesn't seem to relate to Drupal but to setting up Samba shares. If that's not the case could you clarify where/how you think Drupal might be getting involved?

Comment: You're correct. I asked here b/c Drupal creates a huge performance issue in Vagrant due to the size of its code base. I was hoping others may have looked for ways around it and found something that worked.

Comment: Don't get me wrong I hope you get a good answer, I'm just not sure how many regulars use Vagrant (it doesn't come up too often so who knows). FWIW my Drupal setup with Vagrant on a Mac is very fast using shared folders so I've never had to resort to something like this...it may be more of a Virtualbox-with-windows (or even hardware) issue

Answer (score 1):

The git project Druphpet is doing exactly what you want to achieve.
https://github.com/alehkot/druphpet

It's using a Samba server under your guest(Ubuntu) accessible via Windows explorer: "\192.168.9.10\data"

For sure you Drupal website becomes really fast, because your webserver is accessing files locally(inside Linux)

The only problem with this approach is that every modifications of your Drupal code inside your Windows text editor (themes, custom module...) become slower because not local.

The other problem is that when the vm is off or crashed, you can't access your Drupal files anymore.